# What does a Remote Desktop Connection risk for both computers?

Tags: malware, vpn, remote-desktop

I recently had a malware issue called "mysearchdial" that installed itself into my home computer's browser because someone didn't pay attention to what they were installing.

I RDP'd into my work computer before this malware was completely removed, and I found that this malware had spread to my browsers at my work PC. Now, this could have been and probably was some sort of browser sync across computers, but it really raised the concern, what am I risking when I RDP to my work PC from my personal computer through a VPN? Is malware easily transferable through that connection?

Comment: Depends on how your company handles it and how you have your client setup. Do you have sharing of resources(hdds, printers) on your client when you connect? Do you connect via Native RDP (mstsc.exe) or through some sort of Java client?

Comment: It is native RDP.

Comment: though it's unlikely the malware spread through RDP, IMHO enabling RDP connections in any OS is a huge security hole.  It simply should not be allowed unless it's absolutely necessary.  3rd party IT companies are huge targets for hackers these days because they can infiltrate one company and often will have RDP access to every client of theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While "RDP"ing you have two very different and separates scenarios, it is very hard for a malware (crapware, virus, trojan...) to infect the RDP client (or server) machine, the only way is exploiting the RDP connection so it exploit the client through a malformed packet and manages to install in the new machine.

I have never seen that and I believe exploiting that is complex enough for most malware not to try to research into that scenario (very poor ROI).

As you have pointed out the most probable cause is the automatic sync between browsers.